# `ssh` treat remote command as hostname

Tags: bash, ssh

I am writing a bash script to read from MPI style `hostfile` and execute remote command with ssh.

```
while read p; do
    arrP=($p)
    ssh_target=${arrP[0]}
    echo ${ssh_target}
    ssh ${ssh_target} "pkill python" < /dev/null

done <hostfile
```

The content of `hostfile` is

```
ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com slots=1
ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com slots=1
```

I got the following error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pkill python: Name or service not known
```

I try to manually run the commandline from shell:

```
ssh ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com "pkill python"
```

and it runs successfully. Thus I assume there may be something wrong in the way I construct the command but I couldn't find it.
If I remove the `< /dev/null` from ssh command, it will run successfully but it will also break the `while` loop. I tried to use `-n` and `-t` but I got the same error.
Any comments and suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: `arrP=($p)` is not array, If it is just two fields, you could just do `read col1 col2` then `"$col1"`  is what you're looking for, otherwise `read -ra p` then `"${p[0]}"`

Comment: From the error message, you can conclude that `ssh_target` is empty. This means that you have to monitor the content of your variables. This means that for debugging you have to turn on `set -x` inside your script and analyze the output.

Comment: @Jetchisel: To be precises, `arrP` **is** an array, but `p` is not an array. However, while I agree that the logic of the script is broken, I think that `arrP` should have a non-empty string at index position 0. No matter what garbage is stored there, `ssh_target` should be non-empty as well. I wonder whether we really see the original script here.

Comment: Tangential to the real question but you need the `< /dev/null` because otherwise `ssh` reads the same stdin as your loop and exhausts it. More explanation and other possible workarounds here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

Answer (score 0):

@user1934428 's comment of `ssh_target` being empty and using `set -x` is right to the target. From the following output it can be seen that the empty line in `hostfile` is the root cause.

```
$ ./kill_python_dist.sh
++ read p
++ arrP=($p)
++ ssh_target=ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
++ echo ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
++ echo ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
++ ssh ec2-34-214-59-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'pkill python'
++ read p
++ arrP=($p)
++ ssh_target=ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
++ echo ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
++ echo ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
++ ssh ec2-34-220-248-224.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 'pkill python'
++ read p
++ arrP=($p)
++ ssh_target=
++ echo

++ echo

++ ssh 'pkill python'
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pkill python: Name or service not known
```

I updated the bash script to check for the empty line and the error is gone

```
while read p; do
    arrP=($p)
    ssh_target=${arrP[0]}
    if [ -z "${ssh_target}" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    echo ${ssh_target}
    ssh ${ssh_target} "pkill python" < /dev/null

done <hostfile
```